# How to set scrollview to my layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

Im new to android..

How to set scrollview to mu layout? please guide me..

In my layout i have four textview four radio buttons and next, previous button so for all these totally i want to set scroll view.. How to implement this?

> ```
>     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> tools:context=".Quesans" >
>  <RadioGroup
>      android:id="@+id/rdgroup"
>      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>      android:layout_below="@+id/que_txt"
>      android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
>      android:orientation="vertical" >
>      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB1" android:text="button1"/>
>      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB2" android:text="button2"/>
>      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB3" android:text="button3"/>
>      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB4" android:text="button4"/>
>  </RadioGroup>
>  <Button
>      android:id="@+id/prv_btn"
>      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/nxt_btn"
>      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nxt_btn"
>      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>      android:text="Previous" />
>  <Button
>      android:id="@+id/nxt_btn"
>      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>      android:layout_below="@+id/rdtxt"
>      android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
>      android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
>      android:text="Next" />
>  <TextView
>      android:id="@+id/rdtxt"
>      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>      android:layout_below="@+id/rdgroup"
>      android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
>      android:text="Nothing is picked" 
>      android:textColor="#0000FF"/>
>  <TextView
>      android:id="@+id/focusarea"
>      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nxt_btn"
>      android:layout_below="@+id/nxt_btn"
>      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
>      android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
>      android:text="" />
>  <TextView
>      android:id="@+id/soltxt"
>      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/focusarea"
>      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/focusarea"
>      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>      android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
>      android:text="" />
>  <TextView
>      android:id="@+id/que_txt"
>      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>      android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
>      android:text="TextView" />
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".Quesans" >
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <RadioGroup
     android:id="@+id/rdgroup"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/que_txt"
     android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
     <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB1" android:text="button1"/>
     <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB2" android:text="button2"/>
     <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB3" android:text="button3"/>
     <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB4" android:text="button4"/>
 </RadioGroup>
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/prv_btn"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/nxt_btn"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nxt_btn"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:text="Previous" />
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/nxt_btn"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/rdtxt"
     android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
     android:text="Next" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/rdtxt"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/rdgroup"
     android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
     android:text="Nothing is picked" 
     android:textColor="#0000FF"/>
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/focusarea"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nxt_btn"
     android:layout_below="@+id/nxt_btn"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
     android:text="" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/soltxt"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/focusarea"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/focusarea"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
     android:text="" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/que_txt"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
     android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i can't see the scroll..if i click i can able to see but can't able to scroll..please guide me..

Comment: add this to your scrollview.. android:scrollbars="vertical"

Comment: Replace

 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Quesans" >
 
by 

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
tools:context=".Quesans" >

Comment: Little bit i can able to scroll but fully i can't able to scroll and see the values..last two textview alone i want to scroll and see other view are all fit to layout...

Comment: In grapical layout i saw the scroll is upto end of my textview not upto full layout so only im able to scroll lightly..What changes to do for this? guide me..

Comment: i am not getting your point...do you want to scroll your whole relative layout or some specific area of your layout?

Comment: sorry i can't able to scroll can't able to drag down..but lightly moves not able to see the values..

Comment: which values are you not able to see?

Comment: down last two textview @+id/focusarea and @+id/soltxt

Comment: you have not specified any text in those textviews. Try adding text to them

Comment: ok...so try adding android:paddingBottom="20dp" to your relative layout which is just above radiogroup

Comment: but your answer is correct, i don't know why im able to scroll i think can give height something like 500dp...

Comment: you need not give height to scrollview. Just make sure you are setting values in your activity. Just check it once by setting values in xml itself instead of setting it through activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Quesans" >
 <RadioGroup
     android:id="@+id/rdgroup"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/que_txt"
     android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
     <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB1" android:text="button1"/>
     <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB2" android:text="button2"/>
     <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB3" android:text="button3"/>
     <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB4" android:text="button4"/>
 </RadioGroup>
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/prv_btn"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/nxt_btn"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nxt_btn"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:text="Previous" />
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/nxt_btn"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/rdtxt"
     android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
     android:text="Next" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/rdtxt"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/rdgroup"
     android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
     android:text="Nothing is picked" 
     android:textColor="#0000FF"/>
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/focusarea"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nxt_btn"
     android:layout_below="@+id/nxt_btn"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
     android:text="" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/soltxt"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/focusarea"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/focusarea"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
     android:text="" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/que_txt"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
     android:text="TextView" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i can't see the scroll..if i click i can able to see but can't able to scroll..please guide me..

Comment: If your elements fit in your screen, you will not be able to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like dat and put all view into relative layout . 
ScrollView have only one direct child its a mendatory.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

 <RelativeLayout
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".Quesans" >
 </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i can't see the scroll..if i click i can able to see but can't able to scroll..please guide me..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"

 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Quesans" >

    //code here

   </RelativeLayout >

   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: i can't see the scroll..if i click i can able to see but can't able to scroll..please guide me..

Comment: ok let i check your full code on my device which version you used ?

Comment: i could scroll layout in my emulator so can you post recent code which you have used?